# Ralink USB Wi-fi Dongle

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, network-manager, ralink

I'm very new to ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 18.04. After update from software updater my wireless usb won't work anymore. But through usb ethernet it's working. I'm really sad. I tried sudo apt update, sudo apt dist-upgrade, then run the same driver I had but still not working. I don't wanna touch the root directory for modification. Please spare me your little time for me. Thank you for your time for reading my sad story. Hoping for your reply.

Below the info for my wireless ralink usb wi-fi dongle.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yPjZNCvsBK/

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        802.11 n WLAN
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800usb
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-38-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         ' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/net/wlx
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4a46ad59-9970-47be-bf4c-d928f8645972 | SKY Broadband